# Way to get rid of side and bottom bar of subform? MS Access

Tags: forms, ms-access

Is there a way to get rid of the left side bar and bottom bar in a subform?
I'm referring to the bars in this image.

[image: Imgur]

I have the form that is being referenced as a continuous form, if that matters.  What I want to try to do is make it look sort of like what this user does in 
[Trying to Make an Efficient Calendar in Microsoft Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408430/trying-to-make-an-efficient-calendar-in-microsoft-access).

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out, all I had to do was set the Record Selectors and Navigation Buttons as No on the form properties of the referenced form.