# Ms Access 42 subforms

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am still stumped on how you make 42 subforms quick. This is the calendar problem. I understand It has been answered by using recordset, but not how, any help would be great

Comment: It sounds like you need to rethink your concept. Seriously.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408430/trying-to-make-an-efficient-calendar-in-microsoft-access

Comment: As Albert states: "The performance bottleneck is not that of using 42 sub forms, but that of having 42 record sets and 42 queries". So if it slow, you may need to study your queries.

Comment: I have one table and a second table with fields 1 to 42 with values 1 to 42 i then link the sub form to one of these fields so only the subforms with data are linked.