# Question about the maximum number of sub reports within a report - Access

Tags: ms-access, report, subreport

Wondering if there is an upper limit on how many sub reports can be put in a report?  I’ve got a report that represents locations at a harbour.  Think of this like a parking/berthage map. There are 43 locations in total, so I have 43 sub reports that are based on an individual query for each location.  Unfortunately, the most sub reports I can get on to the report is 37.  After that the program gives the error that there is not enough memory.

I tried to solve this problem by putting more that one query in each sub report but this does not seem possible.  If it is possible to put more than one query in each sub report that would be great to get some direction as to how this is accomplished as I could not figure this out.
The only solution I could come up with is putting six locations on a second report. So I have one repor

This gets the job done, but the ideal would be to see all the information on one report/page.  The information in the sub reports can change daily so the main report gets run often, sometimes more than once each day as things change.

Access version is 2309 -Microsoft 365
Computer
8GB
64 bit
Windows 10 Pro

[image]

This is the query for location E1D1 (35)

```
SELECT BOAT.BOAT_NAME, LOCATION.Float, LOCATION.DOCK, 
LOCATION.ORIENTATION, BERTHAGE.BERTH_WEEK, BERTHAGE.BERTH_YEAR
FROM LOCATION RIGHT JOIN (BOAT RIGHT JOIN BERTHAGE ON BOAT.BOAT_ID = 
BERTHAGE.BOAT) ON LOCATION.LOC_ID = BERTHAGE.LOCATION
WHERE (((LOCATION.Float)="E1") AND ((LOCATION.DOCK)="D1") AND 
((LOCATION.ORIENTATION)="North") AND 
((BERTHAGE.BERTH_WEEK)=DatePart("ww",Now(),2,2)) AND 
((BERTHAGE.BERTH_YEAR)=Year(Now())));
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the report with it's subreports? Perhaps there's a way of combining them or optimising them to use less memory that would solve your problem.

Comment: I've added it.  Where you see 'WORKSLIP 2 (6)" is where there would ideally be a sub report, but I've moved that location to the second report as it is not as active as the floating docks.

Comment: There is a limit of 754 controls and sections over lifetime of report or form. Only 1 query per form or report. There is no code for analysis and as presented this is basically a design issue and not really appropriate for SO. Suggest posting in a discussion forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis.

Comment: What is sample query used in subreports? Is it only a boat name? This arrangement is similar to a monthly calendar which I bet could be adapted. Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408430/trying-to-make-an-efficient-calendar-in-microsoft-access

Comment: I've attached a query in the original post.  I will look at the calendar in the post above.  My apologies on posting to the wrong form.  I did not consider this a design issue per say, it was more functionality in my mind, with the goal of getting a one page report as opposed to a two page report for the end users.

Comment: And another calendar discussion https://www.utteraccess.com/topics/1969978